# Regular expression to get value between open parantheses and a comma using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to extract a string between a `('` and `',`

here is what it looks like:

[image: ('I enter in {string}',]

and I want to extract

```
I should see the menu page
I create a custom order with create your own salad
I dismiss the dietary preferences menu tooltip
```

These are gherkin steps in my automation framework and I've tried using

```
\'[^']+'
```

but this also returns any imports that I have in my page classes such as '../src/etc' which I don't want.

Comment: So why not `/\('(.*?)',/`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capturing group and a generator like this:

```js
const input = "('I enter in {string}', ('blbl',"

const regex = /\('([^']*)',/ig;

function* getResults(input, regex) {
  let match;

  while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
      yield match[1];
  }
}

const results = [ ...getResults(input, regex) ];

console.log(results);
```

Shorter solution:

```js
const input = "('I enter in {string}', ('blbl',"

const regex = /\('([^']*)',/ig;

const results = [ ...input.matchAll(regex) ].map(([, x]) => x);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: How do I capture all strings matching this regex?. I am reading from a file and there are multiple strings that I need to extract. I tried let array = fileContents.match(/\('(.*)',/g); . However I am getting an array of strings such as ["('I go to the payment page',", "('I close the menu', "]

Comment: @Orbita1frame I've edited my answer with two solutions for your requirement.